# how can i complete this function

Tags: asp.net, gridview, sqldatasource

iam now doning some asp.net page that display group of images in grid view but this image must be a link to another page displaying the image and its details
this is the function i use to get images from data base:

```
<script language="C#" runat="server">
   public void getImages ( Object src, GridViewRowEventArgs e ) {
      if ( e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow ) 
      {
         DataRowView rowView = ( DataRowView ) e.Row.DataItem;
         string imageid = rowView [ "imgid" ].ToString ( );
         string  imgstring=rowView ["image"].ToString();
         byte[] img = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(imgstring);
         TableCellCollection myCells = e.Row.Cells;
      }
   }
</script>
```

by this code i get the image from the database but as array of bytes 
i couldn't convert the bytes to its original images

this is the grid view that display images

and its coulmns are :

```
     <asp:hyperlinkfield 
        datanavigateurlfields="image"
        datanavigateurlformatstring="Default2.aspx?id={0}" >
        <controlstyle borderwidth="1" borderstyle="inset" />
     </asp:hyperlinkfield>
      <asp:hyperlinkfield
        datanavigateurlfields="imgid"
        datanavigateurlformatstring="Default2.aspx?id={0}">
        <controlstyle borderwidth="1" borderstyle="inset" />
     </asp:hyperlinkfield>
     <asp:hyperlinkfield
        datanavigateurlfields="imgid"
        datanavigateurlformatstring="Default2.aspx?id={0}">
        <controlstyle borderwidth="1" borderstyle="inset" />
     </asp:hyperlinkfield>
  </columns>
```

and this is the sql data source

" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT [imgid],[image] FROM [Image]">
    
 now when running the code a grid view is shown embty

what i must change or add to make the images to display in the grid view and when clicking on any image in it go to another page has the image and it's details

Answer (score 0):

When you have images stored in database, best way to get them for displaying in the gridview, or any other place on the web page is to use HTTP Handlers.
[Check this link out](http://www.jigar.net/articles/viewhtmlcontent3.aspx)